# Cat6 cabling faulty? Any way I can salvage this?

Tags: networking, ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, rj-45, cat6

I got cat6 cables set-up with my house when it was built. Everything seems to be working fine, until last week when I tried for the first time one of the last RJ45 wall sockets I was yet to use.

I noticed that the connection was not coming up at all. So I opened the wall socket and gently pulled the socket (still wired to the ethernet cable) out. **Seems that after a while fidgeting with the cable, I got a connection (LEDs of my laptop's RJ45 socket came up) and a solid `ping -t 8.8.8.8` running for a few minutes until I manually stopped it**.

I decided to screw the socket back into the wall at this point, and of course the connection stopped working. So I thought to myself that the cable might be broke at the female (wall socket) end, or perhaps the socket is faulty.

I decided to have a go at this again today, and I re-wired the RJ45 female module (by the way, it is wired as T586B), and I still got a faulty connection. A ping -t would show it working from time to time.

To check if it the module is the culprit, I decided to terminate the wall end with a RJ45 male, thus making it a long patch cable to my switch. Still no joy. I also re-did the RJ45 male connection at the other end (the one that goes into my Switch) just to be sure.

At some point I tested the cable with a standard cable tester (those with the 8 LEDs) and I noticed that the main terminal sending the signal (the one that takes the 9V battery) now has all 8 LEDs coming up as normal. The other terminal however, shows a short circuit between cables 2, 6 and 7 (orange, green, white/brown).

I don't recall the sequence of events at this point but I am sure that in earlier tests, the main cable tester terminal wouldn't have all light coming up.

Now that the cable is in this male-to-male configuration, the LEDs at my laptop's ethernet jack are always on, but somehow this is worse than before. A `ping -t` would rarely provide me with a return (but it still does it, although rarely).

**To sum up:** the cable behaved before as if it had a faulty connection, now it behaves as it if has a short circuit.

I wonder at this point what are my options?

- Could it be that the issue is still at the ends of the cable, rather than in the middle of it? I am inclined to believe so due to the changes in the behaviour as I refitted the connectors. But it could be that I just jiggled the cable enough for whatever fault that was in the middle to be in short-circuit.
- If worse comes to worse, I would be willing to salvage this Cat6 cable and turn it into a 100BASE-TX with a non-standard cable layout, but I am not sure if this is an option due to the bad luck with the short circuit (orange, green, white/brown). I reckon that I could end up with some cross-talk.

I don't want to keep trimming this cable anymore without some certainty, and I will be willing to get professional help at this point.

PS: Hindsight is a wonderful thing. If I am ever buying a house again, I will demand conduits for network cables, and for all of them to be tested in front of me.

Answer (score 1):

Most often short circuits and breaks are caused at the termination - the sockets. A cable that hasn't been abused physically doesn't fail.

So, carefully inspect and possibly redo/replace the sockets. If you can't make out the shorts, remove sockets from both sides and test again. Check cabling for physical damage, especially crushing, sharp bending (less than four diameters) and kinking. Use a proper LSA tool for crimping, it's cheap.

Also, make sure that you keep the pairs together - mismatched pairs cause extensive attenuation and extreme crosstalk. Do not undo, reverse or overdo the pair twist rate.

Comment: Thanks. No sign of obvious damage at either end. We already re-did the female side about 2 times. I re-did the other end (male) once. If my memory doesn't fail, I think we had diferent results with the cable tester each time. I decided not to try anymore (save cable!!!) until I  get a professional to look into it. One thing I never did was to look into other female outlets that are working fine and compare the job. Bear in mind that tester looks fine at the powered end, but not at the other end.

Comment: We also tried making both ends male and still cable seems dodgy. I honestly home we can blame my cabling skills, which means there is hope. I am no professional, but I am not a noob either. 

Comment: If a simple cable tester already shows faults in the cable there's no use trying to run a network. "Different results" clearly indicates there's something fundamentally wrong with either the cable or the termination. "tester looks fine at the powered end" doesn't make sense - you know that the source end (with the battery) just indicates what it's testing and the sensor end shows the result, don't you?

Comment: Different results meaning that I got different result each time I re-did the termination for the cable. So I am hoping that the problem is the termination. I am starting to look for a professional to help me with this, since I am also looking for other stuff to be done anyway.

Comment: Do note that during the first time I troubleshooted this, I just opened the wall plate and fidget the cable, which gave me a solid ping for about 5 to 10 minutes. So fingers crossed that this is just a fault at the termination?

Comment: Apparently, there are loose contacts or bad insulation if the jack is sensitive to touch and motion.